# What is a difference between 2 forms of self-invoking function call?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was reading Backbone.js annotated source code
http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html
 and noticed a strange (for me) form of function invocation

```
(function(root, factory) {
  // omitted     
  root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);       
  // omitted
}(this, function(root, Backbone, _, $) { /* omitted */ })); <---- HERE
```

I can not understand why they choose this form of immediate function invocation with parameters specified after curly brace `}(params)` but not after a function closing bracket `)(params)` like in my 2nd example below.

Below are simplified examples.

First example returns error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (**

```
function(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}(10, 20);
```

When second example executes a function, returning 30

```
(function(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}(10, 20));
```

**Why choose a second example?** I thought for a function to become a self-invoking it must have this form of invocation:

```
(function(x, y) {
  return x + y;
})(10, 20);
```

Comment: You first example the function needs a name - that's why you're getting the error: `var a = function(x, y) { return x + y; }(10, 20); console.log(a); // 30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `function` is the first token in a statement, then it's assumed to be a function **statement.** A function statement is **not an expression,** so you can't immediately invoke it.

Putting the opening parenthesis `(` before the `function` keyword lifts it into expression position, so you will now have a function **expression,** which will end at the closing `}`, so you can call it there, regardless of whether it's just the function expression that is wrapped in parentheses or the entire call expression. It's an expression either way, so you **can** call it.

> I thought for a function to become a self-invoking it must have this form of invocation:

Why did you think that is the case? You have to think about why the parentheses have to be there -- it's just a work-around for the ambiguity in the grammar of JavaScript, nothing special at all. "Self-invoking functions" are just a pattern and definitely not a special piece of syntax.

Some argue that the second form (where the entire invocation is wrapped into parentheses) is better because it emphasizes the purpose and the integrity of the self-invoking expression better.